# How to convert string to number?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

How to convert **"4,250,000.40"** to **4,250,000.40** that is converting string to number by remaining the commas and dots? using JavaScript

Comment: You can't, as what you want is not a valid number

Comment: Try `+"4,250,000.40".replace(/\,/g,'')` and you'll get `4250000.4`

Comment: thanks for your reply,Can I add earlier commas and dots to the converted number?

Comment: @adeneo "avoid answering questions in comments"

Comment: No, you can't add commas, and you can only have one period, otherwise it's not a valid number. That's why strings are used for presenting numbers in certain ways etc.

Comment: @VenkateshMachineni Once you convert it from a string to a number, it is stored in memory as a bunch of 1s and 0s. You can't add commas to 1s and 0s.

Comment: Challenge accepted `000111101011,,,,,1000110` <- look ma !

Comment: I have data in JSON format as "Price":"100,00", I need to sort a column values based on Price in a table. Since price value is in string format, sorting is not working as expected.Please suggest how to proceed?

Comment: Sort by numbers, keep the strings

Comment: I need to sort only price column based on values,Did not understand, please elaborate

Answer (score 4):

You can use parseFloat(str) to convert a string to a number, but first you need to remove the commas from the string, as parseFloat doesn't work for numbers with commas in them.

```
parseFloat(str.replace(/,/g, ""));
```

Comment: Can I add earlier commas and dots to the converted number after converting?

Comment: Once it's converted, it is a number and not a string. You can't add commas to numbers, as their memory representation does not allow for anything other than data pertaining to the number's value.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str =  "4,250,000.40";
str = str.replace(/\,/g, "")
console.log(str)
console.log(parseFloat(str).toFixed(2))//to always show 2 decimal places
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly convert `"4,250,000.40"` to a number in vanilla JS, let alone preserve commas. `4,250,000.40` is not a valid number in JavaScript, because a `comma` is an illegal character in a `Number`.

you can use regex to delete commas, then use [`Number.parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat), but then number formatting is lost. Instead, I suggest using a number formatting library like [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/). To convert `"4,250,000.40"` to a `numeral` you'd use:

```
const num = numeral("4,250,000.40");
```

you can reformat your number using the `format()` method like so:

```
const formatedNum = numeral("4,250,000.40").format('0,0.00');
console.log(formatedNum); // "4,250,000.40"
```

Here's a working example, including more cool formatting:

```js
const num = numeral("4,250,000.40");
const formatedNum = num.format('0,0[.]00');
console.log(formatedNum); // "4,250,000.40"
// you can format number as money
console.log(num.format('$0,0[.]00')); // $4,250,000.40
// you can use abbreviations like k or m
console.log(num.format('$0.00a')); // $4.25m
// you can use financial notation
console.log(numeral("-4,250,000.40").format('($0,0)')); // ($4,250,000)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```